# In Android system, for every change in date and time, is there a way to know if the user has advanced or delayed the device time or date?

Tags: java, android

The application already receive the system intent ACTION_TIME_CHANGED.
but I need a way to identify if the user advance or delayed date or time.

the scenario is the following:

- user's device start with the present date Dec/2022
- So, user change date to Dec/2019. (backward date, based on previous date Dec/2022)
- Then, user change date to Jan/2020. (forward date, based on previous date Dec/2019)
- now, user change date to Jan/2021. (forward date, based on previous date Dec/2020)
- again, user change date to Jan/2020. (backward date, based on previous date Dec/2021)

... and so on...

Id like to identify the type of date change (backward or forward) based on the last change, and not from the present date from a web provider.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to know if the date and time in user's device is true and present in that case you can use a time API to get time from a web provider and compare it to the devices time.

```
Instant onThisMachine = Instant.now() ;
Instant remote = Instant.parse( stringFromRemoteService ) ;
Duration delta = Duration.between ( remote , onThisMachine ) ;
boolean thisMachineIsBehind = delta.isNegative() ;
```

These classes are built into Android 26+. For earlier Android, use the latest tooling to access most of the *java.time* functionality via “API desugaring”.

Comment: Not exactly this case... i want to know based on the previous date or the date after last change. I put the scenario in the question body